# Ruby-Rubocop not working on vscode

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, rubocop

``` /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:289:in ``find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem rubocop (>= 0.a) with executable rubocop (Gem::GemNotFoundException) from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:308:in ``activate_bin_path' from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/rubocop:23:in ```'

This is the error I keep getting whenever I type something. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Does running `rubocop` work from the command line? What is the result of `which rubocop`? Does running `/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/rubocop` work, from the command line? Have you tried reinstalling the gem?

Comment: @TomLord hi, `which rubocop` returns `/Users/me/.rbenv/shims/rubocop` and running the rubocop command from the command line works and it inspects the project.

Answer (score 11):

After many agonising hours and reading other solutions I finally deduce that the answer was in installing Rubocop from the root. Below steps worked when I tried.
You first need to go the **root** in your terminal. 
Install Rubocop then find the path and add it to the execute path in Rubocop settings

```
$ cd ~
$ gem install rubocop
$ which rubocop
Paste location given in Ruby-Rubocop configuration settings > Execute Path
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/
```

Comment: Where are rubocop settings located? I looked around for a `.yml` file where the settings are, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

I can propose you 2 solutions because I had experienced the same problem:

- For me installing the `bundler` with `sudo` -> `sudo gem install bundler` fix the issue.
- Also it can be a mistake coming from you `RubyGems` version. It seems like `ruby -v2.5` has a compatible problem with `RubyGems -v2.7.3`. So try upgrading the `RubyGems` to `-v2.7.4` using the `gem update --system` command.

Comment: What is your `RubyGems` version? Also what is the `rubocop` version you are trying to install and what OS you are using?

Comment: `RubyGems` is 2.7.7

Comment: and i'm looking to install latest version of rubocop that is available on vscode marketplace

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who downloaded Ruby26-x64 and is having the same issue. It is probably because of the install locations and that your C://Users//you//whatever doesn't exist. To fix this I simply checked where ruby was installed on my C drive. For me, it downloaded by default into a file called Ruby26-x64 on my C drive. Open the folder go to bin and double check that there is a rubocop.bat somewhere. Copy paste the path, into settings.json. Should look something like this.

```
"ruby.rubocop.executePath": "C:\\Ruby26-x64\\bin\\",
```

Note that this is a solution I found on Windows 10, I don't know about Mac.

EDIT:

Settings.json can be found by going to File>Preferences>Settings>Workbench

and under "Editor Associations", you will see a button that says Edit in settings.json, there are many ways to open your settings.json file, this is just one.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem on M2 mac recently. `rubocop` was running from terminal, but it wasn't working in my sublime. Solved by `sudo gem install rubocop -v [required_version]`

Answer (score -1):

After installing rubocop gem `gem install rubocop`

Run `bundle install` and then run `rubcop` again. It functioned for me.