# Error on config Rubocop for VSCODE in WSL2

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, rbenv, rubocop

First I've checked if the gem is actually installed:

`rubocop -v => 0.92.0`

Then, checking where's rubocop executable is installed:

`which rubocop` => `/home/joao/.rbenv/shims/rubocop`
in rbenv:
`rbenv which rubocop` => `/home/joao/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/bin/rubocop`

In `VSCODE > Settings.json`: `"ruby.rubocop.executePath": ""` as recomended https://github.com/misogi/vscode-ruby-rubocop#configuration

When I try to execute: `command /home/joao/.rbenv/shims/rubocop returns empty output! please check configuration.` and `/home/joao/.rbenv/shims/rubocop is not executable`

So I tried to manually add the path: `"ruby.rubocop.executePath": "/home/joao/.rbenv/shims/"`
The same error persists: `command /home/joao/.rbenv/shims/rubocop returns empty output! please check configuration.` and `/home/joao/.rbenv/shims/rubocop is not executable`

Then I tried the path of `rbenv which rubocop` => `"ruby.rubocop.executePath": "/home/joao/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/bin/"`
The same error persists: `command /home/joao/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/bin/rubocop returns empty output! please check configuration.` and `/home/joao/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/bin/rubocop is not executable`

A last try: create a bash script in windows to point to rubocop.

In: c:\my_scripts I created a `rubocop.bat` having:

```
@echo off
bash.exe -c "~/.rbenv/shims/rubocop %*"
```

Then in VSCODE: `"ruby.rubocop.executePath": "c:/my_scripts/",`
still the same erros: `command c:/my_scripts/rubocop returns empty output! please check configuration.`
and `c:/my_scripts/rubocop is not executable`.

I have no idea whatelse I can do.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I just gave up from `ruby-rubocop` extension and installed `Ruby Solargraph`.
Works like a charm.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401191/ruby-rubocop-not-working-on-vscode -- Check out this post.

Answer (score 3):

Try updating rubocop version to 1.9.1
(running this should work)

```sh
gem install rubocop
```

Answer (score 0):

I had slightly more luck using the UNC paths for `ruby.rubocop.executePath` - as well as creating a `rubocop.bat`. So, I had in my settings:

```
"ruby.rubocop.executePath": "\\\\wsl.localhost\\Ubuntu\\home\\charles\\.rbenv\\shims\\",
```

and I used your `rubocop.bat` file which VS Code on Windows seems to want. This was (unusably) slow although it did appear to work. I am using WSL2.